# Users unable to search redirected profile folders

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, search, folder-redirection

All of our clients are using Windows 7. Our file server is Server 2008 R2. We have redirected users' profile folders (My Documents, My Pictures, Favorites, My Videos) to a share on the file server (`\\server\UserProfiles\`). Inside the UserProfiles share is a folder for each user. When we created the UserProfiles folder, we gave it the following permissions to the users' group per MS's recommendations/best practices:

- Create Folder/Append Data, List Folder/Read Data, Read Attributes, Traverse Folder
- Apply to: This folder only
- Creator/Owner has full control of subfolders and files only.

We have offline files enabled for the profile folders, and we have disabled indexing of offline files.

Whenever users try to search their documents, they get an instant response stating "no items match your search." Those of us who are administrators (like me), we can search our files just fine. I ran across [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/7f91bedd-1ac2-4faf-a4e5-7d4569341f22/) thread, but our users already have read/traverse permissions for the root folder. What else can I check to fix this problem? It's affecting all of our users.

Comment: Does `SYSTEM` have any access rights?  We had to give it read and execute access to our DFS roots where we store our user folders, and I think it may have been because searching didn't work without it.

Comment: `SYSTEM` has full control of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Traverse folder permission configured for both the \server\UserProfiles share and the actual folder right?

Comment: I have set the traverse folder permission for only the folder (via the security tab). I can't find where I would set that for the share.

Comment: Its almost where you created the share itself. Navigate to the actual folder thats being shared as UserProfiles on the server. Right click, click properties, click the sharing tab, click advanced sharing, then permissions. 

Try it with giving users read and write access to the share. Then on the security tab of the folder make sure they have Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, and read permissions.

Still as 'this folder only' then you'll need to make sure each individual user, the administrator, and the system have access to their folders.

Comment: For the sharing permissions, Everyone has read/write. For the permissions on the security tab, the group has special permissions:  Create Folder/Append Data, List Folder/Read Data, Read Attributes, Traverse Folder (Apply to: This folder only. Should I add "Read Permissions" to that? When logged into the user's workstation, I can navigate to \\server\UserProfiles and all the users' folders are listed.